# Setup router to redirect one IP address to another

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, redirection

I was wondering how I would go about setting up my router to redirect traffic intended for one server (IP address) to a different one. For example, if someone wants goes to [www.abcdefg.com](http://www.abcdefg.com), the router would instead redirect and return a different IP address with a different website.

Essentially, I would like to have the router look for traffic destined for a particular IP address and reroute it to a different one.

Comment: Do you happen to own the domain name that you want to redirect away from? Otherwise, it's unlikely because browsers nowadays can use [DNS over HTTPS](https://blog.cloudflare.com/dns-encryption-explained/).

Comment: That depends on the router. For a computer, one does it via the `hosts` file.